# How to remove the white border from my heat map using python

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, heatmap

I've generated 2000 heat maps using seaboard in python3. The problem is that it makes a white border as well. I only want to save the heat map. I want to remove these white borders because I want to train my model based on these heat maps and I think having these borders might mess-up the result. Will having these borders matter since each heat map would have this border?

The code I wrote to generate these heat maps.

```
for i in range(len(h1)):
    ax = sns.heatmap(h1[i], yticklabels = False,xticklabels = False, cbar = False)
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(path.join(outpath,"neutral_{0}.png".format(i)))
```

Actual heat map 
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you really have same size heat map pictures, you can try trimming them by one more step.

Use `PIL`(`pillow`)  module to do this work.

For example:

```py
from PIL import Image

for i in range(len(h1)):
    im = Image.open("neutral_{0}.png".format(i))
    im = im.crop((left, upper, right, lower)) # You have to adjust parameter here
    #im = im.crop((100, 75, 300, 150)) # ↓ 
    # you will get an image which size is (width=200, height=75)
    im.save("neutral_crop_{0}.png".format(i))
```

The coordinates of these  parameters (left, upper, right, lower) are measured from the top left corner of your input image.

Comment: I tried this but I get an error: **System Error : tile cannot extend outside image**

Comment: Make sure that your parameters are measured from your input image top left. `right` and `lower` are not your new image's width and height.